# How to add a checkbox for a row in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to add a checkbox at the end of each row and then evaluate if the checkbox is checked or not in another cell. Is there an easy way to do this without a macro?
If this is possible only with using a macro, what alternatives do I have, or did somebody already do this and can give me his/her macro?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.  I will demonstrate using Excel 2007.

**Using fonts:**
I went to Wingdings and added a Checkmark in `A1` (character code is **`0252`**).  In regular text, this is **`ü`**.  Then in cell `B1` I put this formula:

```
=if(A1="ü", 1, 0)
```

If `A1` has a check in it, then `B1` will have a `1`. If `A1` does not have a check, then `B1` will have a `0`.

**Using form controls:**

- Show the developer tab in the Ribbon.
- Insert --> Form Controls: CheckBox
- Draw the checkbox where you want it.
- Select the checkbox, click Properties in the Menu
- For Cell link, enter the address of the cell you want to link this checkbox to.

Now when you check the box, the cell will read `TRUE`. If it's unchecked, it will read `FALSE`. Also, if you enter anything other than a zero in the cell, the box will be checked.

Comment: +1 This is the way I do it. Wingdings are your friends!

Comment: Using the same method, you could use the letter X as a checkmark. Your if statement would read `=if(A1="x","There's an X in A1", "No X in A1")` - This works whether the x is capitalized or not.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative answer, I use this way:

**Using Conditional Formatting** (Simple way)

1. Select the column you want to show a check mark.
2. Use `Conditional Formatting / Icon Sets / Indicators / ...` rule.
3. Add number `1` in one of cells.

---

At step 2 you can use `New Rule ...`:

1. Set `Format Style` to `Icon Set`.
2. Select your favorite `Icon Style` from drop-down list.
3. Flag `Show Icon Only` option.

   > This flag will hide values -`0` or `1`-.
4. For first icon -that is check mark-:

   1. Set operator of  to `>`.
   2. Set `Value` to `0`.
   3. Set `Type` to `Number`.
5. For second icon -that is yellow exclamation-:

   1. Select `Red Cross` for `Icon` from drop-down list.
   2. Set operator to `>=`.
   3. Set `Value` to `0`.
   4. Set `Type` to `Number`.

By using this new rule only 0 will be a `Cross Red Icon` and values greater than 0 will be `Green Check Icon`.